# django - NoReverseMatch at /url/ - weird issue

Tags: python, django

I am stuck on this thing.

urls.py

```
print 'test before'
urlpatterns = patterns('horoscopes.views',
  url(r'^$', 'index', name="index"),
  url(r'^(?P<sign_name>\w+)/(?P<sign_num>\d+)/$', 'horoscope_detail', name="horoscope_detail"),
)
print 'test after'
```

html

```
<a href="{% trans 'Capricorn' as capri %}{% url 'horoscope_detail' capri 0 %}">
    Capri
</a>
```

views.py

```
def horoscope_detail(request, sign_name, sign_num):
   # ...
```

I just keep getting:

> Reverse for 'horoscope_detail' with arguments '(u'Capricorn', 0)' and
>   keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

the `"test before"` and `"test after"` are being printed.

what am I doing wrong here? regexp seems to be correct, but really confusing..

Comment: Probably a stupid question but does the item matching 'Capricorn' and 0 *definitely* exist in the database? (I'm presuming it's a test database from your other code)

Comment: @cms_mgr This error doesnot relate to db. The route isnot even passing thru urls.py, this is the problem now.

Comment: have you tried like this: `{% url 'horoscope_detail' sign_name='capri' sign_num=0 %}` ?

Comment: @andrean yep, but the same error. in fact, arguments and keyword arguments dont make difference in named urls, right?

Comment: hmm that's right, I just saw it says 0 patterns tried, is your app's `urls.py` included in the root url config? and the root url config specified in `settings.py`

Comment: @andrean this was my first doubt, but ``"test before"`` and ``"test after"`` are being printed which means, urls.py is being loaded correctly, right?

Comment: do you have `django_extensions` in your installed apps maybe? if so, `python manage.py show_urls` would output all the available patterns

Comment: @andrean my thing is: i hooked my app into django_cms :(. show_urls is showing only django cms urls which is right.

Comment: oh, that might be the problem, have you looked maybe at http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/extending_cms/app_integration.html#application-and-instance-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the *Django CMS* docs stated here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/extending_cms/app_integration.html#application-and-instance-namespaces, the app namespace needs to be specified in order to successfully reverse urls. So something like this should work:

```
{% url 'myapp_name:horoscope_detail' capri 0 %}
```